# how can I serialize ckeditor "richtextfield" in django rest api?

Tags: django-rest-framework, ckeditor

I have a field in models that is richtextfield and I want to add it to the views using serializer. it worked fine in the admin page but not in the browser page.
I am using django rest framework, I am planning to use front end framework.

I don't know exactly how the field will look like in CreateAPIView.

Comment: Can you describe why it's not working in the browser page? It'll be helpful if you can provide your Model and Serializer, and View (, Viewset or Router) classes.

Comment: actually, I am facing another problem, all my views are giving me 404: ("detail": "Not found."), I am using CreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, I am not using viewsets. it was working before adding new models and ckeditor so I am supposing that  its fault.

Comment: Assuming you're requesting the 'retrieve' endpoint for a specific model (usually with an id/pk in the URL) you'll want to check the url is correct, the request is authenticated properly / permissions are appropriate on the View, and that the Model you're retrieving actually exists in the database.

Comment: after digging deeper in this issue I got this: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2773
I installed django favicon but still not working, do you know a solution, please?

Comment: Unlikely that's related to your issue... unless you're specifically requesting  the /favicon.ico resource. Suggest you provide details of the resource (URL) you're actually requesting and both the HTTP response headers and body. You can do this via the browser, the shell (e.g. curl / wget) or an API test agent (e.g. Postman).

Comment: Thank you @dwight for helping me solving the problem. The issue was in the urls priorities, I gave the same first name for all(profile/create, update, view), I changed the createview url making it create/profile, and it worked. Another issue poped out, the user_id i was requesting to fill the profile field, i was using StringField with defaultuser I changed it to hiddenField, then it worked perfectly.